# strftime() in PHP8.1

Tags: php

How to convert a UNIX timestamp into a formatted datestamp?

`strftime` is deprecated

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'da_DK');
strftime('%B', time());
```

I want to print the month in Danish eg. `Januar`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/setlocale with first argument `LC_TIME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter)

```php
$format = new IntlDateFormatter('da-DK', IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 
              IntlDateFormatter::NONE, NULL, NULL, "MMMM");
$monthName = datefmt_format($format, time());
echo $monthName;
```

Comment: This looks very complicated to print something simple as a date

Comment: You can always hide this under some helper functions or classes

Comment: Where can I find information about the pattern? Like `F m Y H:i` or how you want to format the date

Comment: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#date-field-symbol-table